# How to follow on Twitter to enable a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter

I have the following code which seems to be not working.

I want button 2 to enable itself right after the follow click on twitter as well as closing the twitter pop up page.

How can I do it and what's wrong with my current code for enabling button 2?

Thanks ahead,

Appsboss7

Code:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function enableButton2() {
            document.getElementById("button2").disabled = false;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="https://twitter.com/BlackShellMedia" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false">Follow @BlackShellMedia</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>
      <input type="button" id="button2" value="button 2" disabled />
  <script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( '#BlackShellMedia' ).click(function() {
        enablebutton2();
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nothing is wrong with your code, the twitter resets.

Comment: Ah, alright. 

Is there a way to do what I need though?

Thanks anyways!

Comment: The twitter will always reset and do its logic, but you can make sure to follow DOM. Try checking if your class equals to their id and then search for contents and apply the css